# Why does my Firefox profile render audio controls incorrectly?

Tags: firefox, audio, firefox-profile

On the left, my Firefox profile.  On the right, the same instillation with a vanilla profile:

[image]

Why could this be happening?

Update: I tried commenting out everything in my userChrome.css, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Have you tried selectively commenting out more and more? What if you were to start infecting the vanilla profile piece by piece with your css?

Comment: @crazysim - I just tried commenting out everything in my userChrome.css and no change.

Comment: Your image is broken. Do you have the original that you can reupload?

Comment: @Gareth - I don't believe I do, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  I forgot I was using a custom theme that was designed for Firefox 3.0.  Reverting to Strata fixed the issue.  :(